# Add next unique value to SQL column

Tags: performance, sqlite, join, optimization

I have two tables which I am trying to join based on two criteria. One of the criteria is that a date from t1 is between a date in t2 and the next date in t2. The other is that the name from t1 matches the name from t2.

I.e. if t2 looks like this:

```
Record     Name     Date
1          A1234    2016-01-03 04:58:00 
2          A1234    2015-12-15 08:34:00
3          A5678    2016-01-04 03:14:00
4          A1234    2016-01-05 21:06:00
```

Then:

- Any records from t1 for Name A1234 with dates between `2016-01-03 04:58:00` and `2016-01-05 21:06:00` would be joined to record 1.
- Any records from t1 for Name A1234 with dates between `2015-12-15 08:34:00` and `2016-01-03 04:58:00` would be joined to record 2
- Any records from t1 for A1234 after the date of record 4 would be joined to record 4
- Any records from t1 for A5678 would be joined to record 3 because there's only one date.

My initial approach is to use a correlated subquery to find the next date. However, due to a large number of records, I determined this would take over a year to execute because it searches all of t2 for the next later date during each iteration. Original SQLite:

```
CREATE TABLE outputtable AS SELECT * FROM t1, t2 d
WHERE t1.Name = d.Name AND t1.Date BETWEEN d.Date AND (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT Date from t2
        WHERE t2.Name = d.Name
        ORDER BY Date ASC )
    WHERE Date > d.Date
LIMIT 1 )
```

Now, I would like to find the next date only once for all records in t2 and create a new column in t2 that contains the next date. This way, I only search for the next date about 400,000 times instead of 56 billion times, significantly improving my performance.

Thus the output of the query I'm looking for would make t2 look like this:

```
Record     Name     Date                    Next_Date
1          A1234    2016-01-03 04:58:00     2016-01-05 21:06:00
2          A1234    2015-12-15 08:34:00     2016-01-03 04:58:00
3          A5678    2016-01-04 03:14:00     2999-12-31 23:59:59
4          A1234    2016-01-05 21:06:00     2999-12-31 23:59:59
```

Then I would be able to simply query whether `t1.Date` is between `t2.Date` and `t2.Next_Date`.

How can I build a query that will add the next date to a new column in t2?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than add the new column, you should just be able to use a query like the one below to join the tables:

```
SELECT
    T1.*,
    T2_1.*
FROM
    T1
INNER JOIN T2 T2_1 ON
    T2_1.Name = T1.Name AND
    T2_1.some_date < T1.some_date
LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 T2_2 ON
    T2_2.Name = T1.Name AND
    T2_2.some_date > T2_1.some_date
LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 T2_3 ON
    T2_3.Name = T1.Name AND
    T2_3.some_date > T2_1.some_date AND
    T2_3.some_date < T2_2.some_date
WHERE
    T2_3.Name IS NULL
```

You can do the same with NOT EXISTS, but this method often has better performance.

Comment: Unfortunately, SQLite doesn't support outer joins. Is there an equivalent that will work with SQLite?

Comment: @NateGardner SQLite *does* support *left* outer joins.

Comment: I don't quite understand how this finds the next unique date. Could you explain that a little more?

Comment: T2_1 gives you all rows with a date before the date in T1. T2_2 then gives you any with dates after T2_2. Finally, T2_3 gives you rows that fall between T2_1 and T2_2, but any matches there are filtered out (T2_3.Name is only NULL if no match was found.) So, you're basically looking for the rows where there is no other row between the other two dates - in other words, they are the most immediate surrounding dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can speed up (sub)queries by using proper indexes.
To check which indexes are actually used, use [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html).

Your original query, without any indexes, would be executed by SQLite 3.10.0 like this:

```
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE t1
0|1|1|SEARCH TABLE t2 AS d USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (name=?)
0|0|0|EXECUTE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 1
1|0|0|SCAN TABLE t2
1|0|0|USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
```

(The "automatic" index is created temporarily just for this query; the optimizer has estimated that this would still be faster than not using any index.)

In this case, you get the most optimal query plan by indexing all columns used for lookups:

```
create index i1nd on t1(name, date);
create index i2nd on t2(name, date);
```

```
0|0|1|SCAN TABLE t2 AS d
0|1|0|SEARCH TABLE t1 USING INDEX i1nd (name=? AND date>? AND date<?)
0|0|0|EXECUTE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 1
1|0|0|SEARCH TABLE t2 USING COVERING INDEX i2nd (name=? AND date>?)
```

Answer (score -1):

I've used this method on tables with around 1 mil rows with success. Obviously, creating an index that will cover this query will help performance.

This approach uses `RANK` to create a value to join against. After creating the `RANK` in a CTE (I use this for readability reasons, please correct for style or personal preference), use a sub-query to join rnk to rnk + 1; aka the *next* date.

Here's an example of what the code looks like using your sample values.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#T2') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #T2

CREATE TABLE #T2
(
    Record INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(10),
    [DATE] DATETIME,
)

INSERT INTO #T2
VALUES (1, 'A1234', '2016-01-03 04:58:00'),
    (2, 'A1234', '2015-12-15 08:34:00'),
    (3, 'A5678', '2016-01-04 03:14:00'),
    (4, 'A1234', '2016-01-05 21:06:00');

WITH Rank_Dates
AS (Select *
,rank() OVER(PARTITION BY #t2.name ORDER BY #t2.date DESC) AS rnk
 FROM #T2)
 select RD1.Record,
 RD1.Name,
 RD1.DATE,
 COALESCE (RD2.DATE, '2999-12-31 23:59:59') AS NEXT_DATE 
 FROM Rank_Dates RD1
    LEFT JOIN Rank_Dates RD2
        ON RD1.rnk = RD2.rnk + 1 
            AND RD1.Name = RD2.Name
ORDER BY RD1.Record -- ORDER BY is optional
;
```

> EDIT: added code output below.

The code above produces the following output.

```
Record  Name    DATE                    NEXT_DATE
1       A1234   2016-01-03 04:58:00.000 2016-01-05 21:06:00.000
2       A1234   2015-12-15 08:34:00.000 2016-01-03 04:58:00.000
3       A5678   2016-01-04 03:14:00.000 2999-12-31 23:59:59.000
4       A1234   2016-01-05 21:06:00.000 2999-12-31 23:59:59.000
```

On a random note. Would using the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in place of hard coding `'2999-12-31 23:59:59.000'` produce a similar result?

Comment: Yes, `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` would be better, especially if someone wants to use this next millennium.

Comment: Does SQLite have rank?

Comment: Chalk that up to me not paying close enough attention to the tags in the original post. The code I posted works in SQL Server.